# Delete attribute with JQuery in IE7

Tags: jquery

```
$(myelem).removeAttr('attributeName');
```

Does not work in IE 7. The suggested workaround is:

```
$(myelem).prop("attributeName", false);
```

or

```
$(myelem).prop("attributeName", null);
```

or

```
$(myelem).attr("attributeName", '');
```

These are all fine if you want to change the rendering or the behaviour. What I need to is to actually remove the attribute from the source. E.g.

`<p align="center">`
should become
`<p>`
The examples above are focused on doing this
`<p align="">`
Which would change the alignment, but the attribute is still there.

Anyone now a way or *really* deleting the attribute?

I'm using JQuery 1.6.1

Comment: In some browsers, "Viewing Source" shows you the originally rendered markup no matter how much you manipulate it. jQuery manipulates the DOM, not your source markup. Inspect the manipulated DOM using Firebug/Developer Toolbar to see what jQuery is actually doing. With that said, what is your goal here? Why *must* you remove the attribute completely?

Comment: XY problem. It would be better if you explained WHY you want to remove the attribute completely, and why setting it to an empty string is undesirable.

Comment: @Cory, Yes I'm aware of that. The HTML I am editing is the content of a WYSIWIG editor. The content is uploaded to a server, where its expected to not have certain attributes.

Comment: @XY, see comment to Cory

Comment: @Tomas You should definitely parse the content from the server then, or some local script before uploading.

Comment: @Jose, I agree. Problem is that the cleaning is client side to be "wysiwig". Redoing this I would surely move in that direction. Jquery cleaning is a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the p tag completely, with a new p tag without the attribute:

```
$(myelem).replaceWith("<p>"+$(myelem).html()+"</p>");
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that, the problem with that is performance, its a big docuement and more importantly; it doesn't keep the attributes I want to keep.

Comment: even though your answer does not help me, it's an answer to the question, so I'll set it as accepted. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
myelem.removeAttribute('attribute name');
```

This should work, as far as I know the only attributes IE7 is unable to remove are event handlers.

See this link for [removeAttribute](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t118) compatibility.

Comment: +1 yes, this should work. Do this and then try to grab that attribute from the element. Betcha you won't find it.

Comment: Yes, it works, but not for all attributes, e.g. contentEditable, datafld. These attributes come from word HTML and I need to remove them.